# how to send id of button into controller in codigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i am new in codeigniter and i am trying to post the button id from view to controller..

i have a **button with pop-up**, clicking on the button will open **the form in popup**, i want to update that **from input into the database** with the help of **button id**, but i am not able to get the id from view.

**VIEW-:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add_comm" data-href="javascript:addC(<?php echo $id;?>);">
<button" class="pull-right btn btn-info" name="user_id"><?php echo $id; ?></button>
</a>
```

**JS-:**

```
function addC(id) {
url = 'controller_foldr/contoller/add_cm/'+id;
passAjaxGetSubmit(url);
}
```

**Controller**

```
function add_cm(){

    $this->load->model('modl_name');

    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $update_cm = $this->input->post('update_cm');//i am getting this  value from the popup form..
```

I don't know i am doing right thing to perform this action..

someone please guide me if i am wrong..please help...

Comment: whats your actual requirement. Please provide more details.

Comment: i want to update the popup's input value in my database with the help of button id..

Comment: there is a simpler solution. That is keep a hidden field with the id of the field and do an ajax post. Hence you can retrieve the data using input method. Do you want me to show how its done?

Comment: yes please...actually i tried that before this that is also not posting value into controller

Comment: just wait i got some problem with the ajax. I will get back to you with a solution asap

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="field_id" value="20" name="id"/>
<button class="pull-right btn btn-info" name="user_id" id="butn">edit values</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
 id = $('#field_id').val();
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url    :'index.php/test/ajax',
            type: "POST",
            data   : {field_id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("values succesfully edited" + data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown) ;

            }
        });
    });
});
```

i have updated the code please replace your code and put this code. Your problem was the anchor tag and all the unnecessery data elements inside.

> Your controller should look like this

```
 class Test extends CI_Controller
{
public function ajax(){
        $id = $this->input->post('field_id');
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

This code will alert the id for you when the form is submitted. Try this code out instead of yours..

Comment: @star please try it out and let me know

Comment: @ Harigovind R   sorry i am replying late but its not working..i need a pop-window when i hit the anchor...after submitting the form its not passing input id but the form input value of popup only

Comment: @star let me have a look at it i will get back to you

Comment: @star please update your code with your controller. Try passing the value of the id as a field inside the form

Comment: @star You made the code unnecessarily complicated by adding data values to the anchor tag. Just make the code simpler so that debugging is easy for you and others.

Comment: @star I have updated the code for you and this is working perfectly for me. Just give it a try. You will get the value inside the success function of the javascript.